# Moving to the Netherlands by car

Tags: customs-and-immigration, automobiles, netherlands

I am Ukrainian and have been living in Poland for the last year. I have a temporary residence there. Soon, I am going to relocate to the Netherlands under the highly-skilled migrant program. I'm thinking to travel with my goods using a car registered in Poland.

Can I drive the car with Polish plates through the Netherlands? If yes, for how long?

P.S. When I go to the Netherlands, I will apply for a BSN as soon as possible.

Comment: This probably belongs on expatriates.SE.

Comment: Do you plan to keep on using your car for commutes in Netherlands, while it is currently registered in Poland?

Comment: It was my plan till I will figure out if its better to register it in Netherlands or drive back to Poland and sell.